Unity methods are not used in Visual Studio
I think this will be something with new version of Unity 6 or Visual Studio...
Code works normally, but it's annoying that the code is faded, does anyone know how to fix it?
I tried regenerating files, removing .sln file, restarting. Doesn't work..
visual studio screenshot

VS doesnt understand what is called what is not when its called from inside the monobehaviour, such as update, start etc

I don't understand, this is from my script, not directly from the monobehavior script. It was never been faded before.

Is this not something about Theme in VS? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

no is not about themes... and it is Visual Studio, not VSC

Have the same issue with some combinations of versions of VS, Unity and packages in each .. sometimes just happens but then it disappears again ^^

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unused-private-member-IDE0051-fading-e/10781612 and https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2024/11/22/customizing-unreachable-code-fading-in-visual-studio-with-visual-commander/
